# Androidで非SDKインタフェースを使用している箇所を特定する方法はありませんか。

Tags: android, android-studio

現在、Android11移行対応をしています。

Android Developer公式サイトに、非SDKインタフェースの使用箇所を特定する方法がいくつかありますが、どの方法も現在のリソースでは対応できません。

Android 11 でのリスト内容の変更
https://developer.android.com/preview/non-sdk-11?hl=ja#r-list-changes

インターフェースが属しているリストの特定
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces?hl=ja#determine-list

アプリの処理を全てテストすることも時間と人員の関係でできませんし、ツールをダウンロードすることもセキュリティ上できません。

AndroidStudioを利用した方法などで他に何かありませんか?

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)では？ 先ずはツールのダウンロードと利用を許さない(おそらく社内の)セキュリティポリシーが1番の問題のように見えます。法律では無いのでしょうから現実に合うように変更した方が良いでしょう。 そうでないとこの件に限らず今後もビジネスに悪影響を及ぼし続けると思われます。

Comment: 個人的にこの質問へベストアンサーをできる人が存在しない可能性を危惧しました。非公式の「完全ではない簡易的な方法」や非公式の「ツールなどを使用しないが同等以上の手間がかかる方法」が回答される可能性がありますが、そもそもセキュリティを大変気にされてる御社でこれらの方法が採用される可能性はありますか？もしあればですが、回答が満たすべき制約条件を漏れなく質問に追記するのが良いかと思いました (それがないと回答者に後出しでその方法は採用できないと伝える事になりそうなので)